# Web Scraping en python

Tags: python, scraping, python-requests, beautifulsoup

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar el modulo bs4 de python para escrapear la web. Lo que estoy intentando hacer es obtener el puntaje de un videojuego en metacritic y buscando por internet y preguntas similares no he podido solucionarlo. Esto es lo que tengo, que lo que intenta hacer es escrapear el nombre del juego.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/ghostrunner"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

nombre = soup.find_all('div', class_="product_title")
review = soup.find_all('div', class_="summary_wrap")

print(nombre)
print(review)
```

El output de este codigo es: []
[]
Esto me ocurre cada vez que intento obtener cualquier cosa en la pagina. Alguna idea para solucionarlo? Gracias!

Comment: metacritic.com bloquea peticiones con el agente de usuario "python/requests". Puedes cambiarlo con `requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "algo"})`

Comment: @braver Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con

```
nombre= soup.find_all("div", {"class":"product_title"})
review= soup.find_all("div", {"class":"summary_wrap"})
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe brevemente lo que hace este código. Lee [answer].